# What is the status icon that looks like a house?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-droid-charge, notification-icons

There is a strange icon that shows up in my status bar only when I'm at a certain restaurant. It looks like a cross between a house and wifi.

I suspect it might be a free wifi hotspot or something related to a nearby phone store, but I can't find any information about it in manual for my phone.

See the following screenshot:

[image: status bar screenshot]

Comment: What is your phone brand and model? What version of Android? Have you installed some custom ROM? If so, which one?

Comment: I'm using a Samsung Droid Charge running 2.3.6, no custom ROM. I had a tag with the model, but it looks like the question was edited to remove that tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the icon that symbolises that the Verizon Network Extender is in use - could it be possible that the restaurant you visit has had one installed/set up?

[Source](https://community.verizonwireless.com/thread/780192)

Comment: That may be it. I'm marking this as the answer, although I have no way of verifying.

Comment: @MattCasto The next time you visit the resturant, ask if they have a network extender :)